# Why is the water vessel overflowing on my air conditioner?

Tags: electrical, walls, leak, cooling, retaining-wall

The ac keeps on  leaking and now there is a bubble formed underneath it. Is there any way to fix this right now?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Commercial equipment is probably off-topic here, but the make and model of the air conditioner might help.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar model pump. About once a quarter I need to take the clear basin out and the float and clean all the gunk off of it then it works fine for a few months. Those mini pumps are really finicky. You could also check the outlet to make sure it isn’t clogged.

Comment: Cleaning will help, I try to avoid using pumps if possible for this reason, in my area it is legal to allow condensate to be drained outside or into the sewer. I find pumps even my own in the past are not taken care of until they have a problem.+